# How to Handle Long Registration Forms

Tags: user-experience

I am putting together a registration form which has about 30 fields (no kidding).  What is the current philosophy on layout?  Put all elements on one form or break them up into a series of steps based on topic?

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a fan of only having the user enter in the LEAST amount possible to create the profile and then allowing them to "turn on" features by finishing the completion of the profile (i.e. registration form)

Don't look at the home depot registration as an example :)

Twitter actually does a pretty good job at this.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to let the user know whats there to be filled.  In most cases you are better off separating fields in sectins / pages, but don't forget to display what (at least how many pages) are left to be filled.

Comment: Also see [this](http://completeusability.com/why-require-registration-part-1/) useful article.